# A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am an administrator in Apple Developer and my profile is deleted. Now when we create a new provisioning profile it gives the error

> valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain.

The certificate request in the keychain is resisted with my profile.

I have also developed a new certificate request with a new Apple Developer profile but this also gives the same problem. How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the little key under your certificate in keychain Access. If you do not you need to revoke your certificates in your developer account and start over

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1618.html